# Why is my code being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple adventure game based around Rock Paper Scissors. All of the logic works as intended, but why does my code get called multiple times when I press the buttons on the level up screen? On the first go around it gets called once, on the second go around it gets call twice, and so forth and so forth.
Here is the initial set up of the game. This method gets called after the player and the enemies stats have been set.

```
//Start of the game
const startOfGame = () => {
    console.log("Hello")
    document.querySelector(".human-player h2").innerHTML = playerName;
    document.querySelector(".human-player h3").innerHTML = `${playerCurrentHP}/${playerMaxHP}`;
    document.querySelector(".computer-player h2").innerHTML = enemyName;
    document.querySelector(".computer-player h3").innerHTML = `${enemyCurrentHP}/${enemyMaxHP}`;
    document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => {
        img.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const previousAttack = document.querySelector(".previous-attack");
            const playerAttack = img.id;
            console.log(playerAttack);
            const enemyAttack = Player.foeAttack(previousAttack.innerHTML);
            console.log(enemyAttack)
            previousAttack.innerHTML = enemyAttack;
            const winner = checkWinner(playerAttack, enemyAttack)
            displayResults(winner, playerAttack, enemyAttack);

        })
    })

}
```

The checkWinner(playerAttack, enemyAttack) simply checks who wins the fight and doesn't get called twice.
Here is the displayResults(winner, playerAttack, enemyAttack) code

```
const displayResults = (winner, pAttack, eAttack) => {
    const okBtn = document.querySelector(".ok");
    const attacks = document.querySelector(".choose-attack");
    const results = document.querySelector(".results");
    const resultsText = document.querySelector(".info h2");
    attacks.classList.replace("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
    results.classList.replace("fadeOut", "fadeIn");
    if (winner === -1) {
        const damage = Player.dealDamageTo(enemy, player);
        console.log(damage);
        playerCurrentHP -= damage;
        if (playerCurrentHP < 0) {
            playerCurrentHP = 0;
        }
        console.log(resultsText)
        resultsText.innerHTML = `${enemyName}\'s ${eAttack} beats ${playerName}\'s ${pAttack}<br>${enemyName} deals ${damage} damage to ${playerName}`;
        document.querySelector(".human-player h3").innerHTML = `${playerCurrentHP}/${playerMaxHP}`;
        document.querySelector(".computer-player h3").innerHTML = `${enemyCurrentHP}/${enemyMaxHP}`;
    }
    if (winner === 0) {
        resultsText.innerHTML = `Both ${playerName} and ${enemyName} chose ${pAttack}<br>No damage is dealt`;

    }
    if (winner === 1) {
        const damage = Player.dealDamageTo(player, enemy);
        console.log(damage);
        enemyCurrentHP -= damage;
        if (enemyCurrentHP < 0) {
            enemyCurrentHP = 0;
        }
        console.log(resultsText)
        resultsText.innerHTML = `${playerName}\'s ${pAttack} beats ${enemyName}\'s ${eAttack}<br>${playerName} deals ${damage} damage to ${enemyName}`;
        document.querySelector(".human-player h3").innerHTML = `${playerCurrentHP}/${playerMaxHP}`;
        document.querySelector(".computer-player h3").innerHTML = `${enemyCurrentHP}/${enemyMaxHP}`;
    }
    //Functiont to continue game if player and enemy are not dead
    if (playerCurrentHP > 0 && enemyCurrentHP > 0) {
        okBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            attacks.classList.replace("fadeOut", "fadeIn");
            results.classList.replace("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
            resultsText.innerHTML = "Choose your next attack!"
            return;
        })
    }

    //Function to reload game if player is dead
    if (playerCurrentHP === 0 && enemyCurrentHP > 0) {
        const endBtn = document.querySelector(".end");
        resultsText.innerHTML = "You have lost";
        okBtn.style.opacity = 0;
        okBtn.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        endBtn.style.opacity = 1;
        endBtn.style.pointerEvents = "all";

        endBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            location.reload()
        })
    }

    //Function to reset the values if enemy is dead, level up the player and create a new enemy to fight
    if (playerCurrentHP > 0 && enemyCurrentHP === 0) {
        results.classList.replace("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
        count++;
        resultsText.innerHTML = "Choose your Reward!<br>The stat you choose will increase by 5<br>(10 if you choose HP)"
        const levelUpScreen = document.querySelector(".level-up");
        attacks.classList.replace("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
        levelUpScreen.classList.replace("fadeOut", "fadeIn");
        console.log(count);

        document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (button.className === "hp") {
                    setUpGame((player.hp + 10), player.power, player.def);
                    console.log(player, enemy)
                    document.querySelector(".human-player h3").innerHTML = `${playerCurrentHP}/${playerMaxHP}`;
                    document.querySelector(".computer-player h2").innerHTML = enemyName;
                    document.querySelector(".computer-player h3").innerHTML = `${enemyCurrentHP}/${enemyMaxHP}`;

                }
                if (button.className === "power") {
                    setUpGame(player.hp, (player.power + 5), player.def);
                    console.log(player, enemy)
                    document.querySelector(".human-player h3").innerHTML = `${playerCurrentHP}/${playerMaxHP}`;
                    document.querySelector(".computer-player h2").innerHTML = enemyName;
                    document.querySelector(".computer-player h3").innerHTML = `${enemyCurrentHP}/${enemyMaxHP}`;

                }
                if (button.className === "defense") {
                    setUpGame(player.hp, player.power, (player.def + 5));
                    console.log(player, enemy)
                    document.querySelector(".human-player h3").innerHTML = `${playerCurrentHP}/${playerMaxHP}`;
                    document.querySelector(".computer-player h2").innerHTML = enemyName;
                    document.querySelector(".computer-player h3").innerHTML = `${enemyCurrentHP}/${enemyMaxHP}`;

                }
                console.log(button);
                levelUpScreen.classList.replace("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
                attacks.classList.replace("fadeOut", "fadeIn");
                resultsText.innerHTML = "Choose your attack";
                return;
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I know its a bit long and I could probably break it up into separate functions or even a different file to make it shorter, but the problem occurs after the comment //Function to reset the values if the enemy is dead, level up the player and create a new enemy.
In particular, the problem shows up in the section with setUpGame() near the bottom of the that section.
I'm still pretty new to website development and JavaScript. So, why is the code being called twice?

Comment: addEventListener's are stacked, if you call startOfGame twice you will have 2 event handlers, you need to clear them

Comment: `if (playerCurrentHP > 0 && enemyCurrentHP > 0) {
        okBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {` ALSO adds the same event listener every time it is true

Comment: So what we are saying: Do NOT have an event listener assigned inside something that can be called more than once

Comment: For future reference, a good way to debug issues before posting on Stack Overflow is to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mplungjan, I now understand what is going on. The code, as it was set up, was doing exactly what it said it did which was ADD an event listener. I had understood that to mean that it made it so that this is what it WOULD do. However, since I added an event listener every time displayResults() was called, it would then would call BOTH (and so on and so on) events event listeners after the first time.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: It is an answer. It explains the WHY the problem occurred. That make it an answer. I just took what mplungjan said and made it the answer so I could close the question.